# I need to update a JSON file in the root of my ASP.NET MVC application with a form post

Tags: asp.net, json, forms, post, razor

I have a simple JSON file at the root of my application **alert.json**

```
{
  "Alerts": [
    {
      "AlertStatus": "true",
      "AlertText": "There is a problem with the Application"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my controller I am already deserilizing it

```
    var sourceDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var alertname = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceDir, "alert.json");
    var alertJsonText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(alertname);
    AlertMessage myAlertDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlertMessage>(alertJsonText);
```

And in my classes.cs file:

```
    public class AlertMessage
    {
        public List<alert> Alerts { get; set; }
    }

    public class alert
    {
        public string AlertStatus { get; set; }
        public string AlertText { get; set; }
     }
```

Im my admin.cshtml the following lines display the JSON values correctly:

```
@Model.AlertMessage.Alerts[0].AlertStatus
@Model.AlertMessage.Alerts[0].AlertTextfile
```

What I want to do is update these value thought the application using a form something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="fname">AlertStatus:</label>
    <input type="text" id="astatus" name="astatus"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">AlertText:</label>
    <input type="text" id="atext" name="atext"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Only authorize uses can reach the admin.cshtml page so I assume the security aspect will not be an issue?

So here is my question: How should the form action be configured and how do I send these new values back to the JSON file? I am open to other suggestions but the a few admin users need to make these changes in the application and they are not developers.